# How to calculate the total probability from multiple probabilities?

Tags: probability

Let's assume that there are multiple characteristics that define a certain disease.
Each characteristic occurs (according to literature) with a certain probability in that particular disease.

Probabilities for disease 1 as follows:
characteristic 1: 0.9
characteristic 2: 0.8
characteristic 3: 0.85
characteristic 4: 0.95

Probabilities for disease 2 as follows:
characteristic 1: 0.9
characteristic 2: 0.8
characteristic 3: 0.85
characteristic 4: 0.04

One would assume that based on these probabilities, it is very likely that what we see here is our disease 1.
The product of all probabilities though gives me a low overall chance:
0.9 x 0.8 x 0.85 x 0.95 = 0.58

The product of probabilities pointing towards disease 2 is significantly lower (0.9 x 0.8 x 0.85 x 0.04 = 0.02), so we could clearly discriminate between the two diseases, mainly because of the discrepancy in the probability for characteristic 4, which more or less excludes disease 2.

Nevertheless I would have assumed that the total probability for disease 1 should be a lot higher, because every single characteristic occurs with a pretty high probability. Also, the more parameters (characteristics) I would add, even with probabilities as high as 0.9 or higher, the lower the final product will be although the chance for this disease should remain very high.

I tried odds and the sum of log odds as well - this doesn't work very well either.

All I have are well known probabilities for multiple characteristics that point towards a certain disease. Based on these, which formula would be best to use for the calculation of the total probability?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It seems that the problem is not quite well defined. What is the aim: to determine which of two cited diseases is more probable, provided that all characteristics are present?

Comment: Exactly. There are certain bio-markers for certain diseases, for each marker there is a well described probability: e.g. marker 1 occurs in 96% of disease 1, while maker 2 is mostly not present (negative) in disease 1 (lets say it is only positive in 4%). So the presence of marker 2 would make disease 1 very unlikely, although there might be multiple other markers pointing towards disease 1.

Comment: I would assume that to compare the two deceases all markers which give the same result for both of them are completely irrelevant.

Comment: This is actually true. So these less relevant markers should receive a lower significance - but their expression strength can slightly differ from the expression strength in other diseases and therefore also point towards them. So I do not want to ignore them completely.

Comment: To be honest, I am talking about 10 - 15 diseases and about 20 bio-markers. Not only their presence or absence matters, but in some cases also the level (high, low,...). For each disease, each marker and it's level/range has a probability. Some markers are described to be present in several diseases, some only in two, some are unique for only one disease. I thought that it would be most comfortable to just use the known probabilities for a total probability calculation.

Comment: I might need some adapted logistic regression here, or maybe even support vector machine? Not an easy task I‘m afraid...

Comment: I find your problem very interesting, but it should be further elaborated. One should probably assume that the list of diseases is complete. Also important is the question whether the deceases exclude each other or may be present simultaneously.

Comment: The list does not have to be "complete" actually I would say. I could as well want to discriminate only between 3 of the diseases of this kind using only 3 or 4 markers. The simultaneous presence of more than one of these diseases is extremely rare. I will try to add an image that might describe the situation better.

Comment: [IMAGE](https://imgur.com/XDOmZAM)

This image shows the different marker expression patterns for individual diseases.